# tensorflow is not using gpu and nvidia-smi: command not found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

the Nvidia card of my system:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1btR.png)

I want to use graphics card for my tensorflow and I have installed and re-installed again but tensorflow is not using GPU and I have also installed my Nvidia drivers but when I run nvidi-smi then a command is not found

my secure boot is disabled
I have set nouveau=0

Comment: There are two problems. First, your tensorflow is cpu version. You should install gpu version by `pip install -U tensorflow-gpu`. Second, you haven't installed CUDA. You should install CUDA from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, please consider adding the text from your terminal to your question post.

Install the GPU version of TensorFlow, by doing

`sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu`.

However, you should have CUDA installed for the TF-GPU to use your GPU. You may download CUDA from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive). I recommend you to use CUDA 9.0 with TensorFlow 1.7